# grid system - smooth transition when column/div gets pushed to next row

Tags: css, animation, angular, css-transitions, semantic-ui

I'm currently using semantic-ui's grid system but this question would also apply to any other grid system (bootstrap...)

I habe four columns in a row in which cards are placed (lots of cards with ngFor from angular2). When I click on a card, it expands to half the row size (I'm using angular 2's ngClass for this)

Now obviously cards on the right side will get pushed to the next row and I want the transition to be "smoothly". Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: You could do something like this, but you'd need JavaScript. Capture the click event, and then detect the 2 cards at the end (as the 2nd card won't get pushed, but the 3rd and 4th will). From here, clone those objects and move them down onto the next row. Make sure they start off the page, and then animate them in from the left to right. Use an equal animation time as you do when growin the card to `half the row` and it should look pretty seemless

Comment: so basically i need to write a method to detect the cards which will get pushed to the next row causing the 'snapping' and manually animate them in?

Comment: I would say that's definitely one way to go about it, yes!

Answer (score -1):

You could add a css transition to the columns. eg:

```
div[class^="col-"] {
  transition: width 0.3s, height 0.3s;
}
```

This selects all div elements with a class starting with `col-` and adds a transition for height and width. you can change the value in seconds to adjust the speed of the transition. This example does not include vendor prefixes. You can read more about transitions here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: thanks for the reply, but this does only animate the change of col and not the "snapping" when a col gets pushed to another row.